# How to connect PHP to MySQL in private subnet VPC

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet

Hi I have two EC2 instances, one in a public subnet and one in a private subnet in my VPC.

```
Web server (EC2) - public subnet
MySQL database (EC2) - private subnet
```

I am not using AWS RDS for the database, I am using EC2.

Here is my PHP code:

```
define ("DB_HOST", "");
define ("DB_USER", "dbuser");
define ("DB_PASS",'dbpassword');
define ("DB_NAME","dbname");
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=".DB_NAME.";host=".DB_HOST;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    return $dbh;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**What do I put in DB_HOST if the EC2 instance is on a private subnet?**

Answer (score 1):

> What do I put in DB_HOST if the EC2 instance is on a private subnet?

The **Private IP** address of the Database EC2 server.

Comment: Wow, surprising I don't know why I didn't try that. It works! Ok, so what would a use case of a NAT gateway be?

Comment: Also, how can I SSH into my private subnet EC2 server?

Comment: @TimmyBalk - The NAT Gateway provides outbound access to the Internet for your instances in the private subnet. For example, to access patches and updates. Without a NAT Gateway (or other routing devices such as VGW, PrivateLink, VPC endpoints, VPC Peering, etc.), the instances in the private subnet can only communicate with other instances in the same VPC.

Comment: @JohnHanley Gotcha! Thank you all for being so patient with me as I learn this! Interesting stuff! What would I need to be able to SSH into my private subnet EC2?

Comment: @TimmyBalk - Create new questions instead of asking via comments.

Answer (score 0):

answering your other question you mentioned in comments

use this for connecting to private instance through public:
type this on you system terminal

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -i key.pem -W %h:%p ec2-user@public_ip' ec2-user@private_ip -i key.pem
```